# Tengo un problema con el editor de WordPress

Tags: wordpress

me pasaron el admin wordpress para poder editar una pagina, y al entrar en el editor no me sale nada y quería saber si saben de algún posible motivo. Dejo una imagen para mayor entendimiento. Para datos extras, me aparece que falta actualizar el WordPress y plugin, no lo hago porque no se si afectara en algo luego en la pagina, agradecería cualquier respuesta. Gracias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo primero que debes validar es que el usuario con el que esta iniciando sesión tenga permisos para visualizar todo completo o con algún tipo de restricción. pero ademas me surge una duda en donde dices "entra al editor y no me sale nada" exactamente a que te refieres?

Comment: Me refiero a que, cuando ingreso para editar me deberia de salir el contenido, cosa que no me aparece nada para editar (como se ve en la imagen)

Comment: Comprendo, existe algún otro usuario admin del sitio? en caso de que si, puede validar si te aparece el contenido , tengo como hipótesis que puede ser temas de permisos, tal vez te falte algún plugin sea elementor, divi, etc o que definitivamente no exista nada y se deba crear!

Comment: Entiendo amigo, y existe otro usuario mas, y ese tiene nivel "autor" y ya accedi ya a el, y lo mismo es

Comment: Una consulta si actualizo todo me podria crear problemas mas graves? asi para estar preparado para otro posible problema

Comment: lo puedes hacer, pero ten en cuenta que antes de hacer algún tipo de cambio relevante siempre es bueno mantener una copia de seguridad reciente en caso de que algún plugin no sea compatible al momento de actualizar, y que sin problema puedas restaura normal, puedes consultar esta guia muy buena https://themeisle.com/blog/backup-a-wordpress-site-for-free/#:~:text=To%20backup%20a%20WordPress%20site%20for%20free%2C%20you%20will%20first,and%20click%20Install%20Now%20%3E%20Activate. en caso de que no sepas como se hace

Comment: Muchas gracias amigaso, justo eso queria hacer y estaba buscando como, ahora mismo hago eso gracias

Comment: Dale, con gusto

Comment: Si logro solucionar hoy, aviso aquí en el comentario, para que puedan saber también como lo solucione.

Answer (score 0):

No entendí del todo su pregunta, pero aquí va mi respuesta.

Se me ocurren varias cosas del porque, primero ve a Screen Options y verifica que todo se este mostrando en pantalla, eso esta en la parte superior de la pagina de edición.

Si te refieres a que no hay contenido en el editor pero si que se muestra en fronted, ingresa a esa pagina en especio y utiliza el plugin [What The File](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/what-the-file/) para verificar si se esta usando una plantilla personalizada, localizada y verifica si el contenido sale de manera estática o dinámica.

También revisa la consola, F12 si estas en Windows para verificar si hay errores, puede que algún plugin este ocasionando problemas, trata de verificar si tienes un plugin que agregue características al editor, talvez no este funcionando como se debe.

Lo recomendable seria hacer una copia del sitio y realizar pruebas en un devsite o bien en localhost, para ver si es problema de la versión del tema o algún plugin en concreto. Tambien prueba a Activar el `Debug Mode` para verificar si WordPress te notifica de algun problema.